# How do we deal with a user that doesn't seem to know the rules?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691856/slash28cu) created the following question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/13088622/561731 which is a **direct** copy and paste from my bigger   [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731) question.

The question has been closed and will be deleted soon.

*But* they way that user has been commenting, I am not sure they understand how Stack Overflow and the SE work:

> Cool, i didn't knew that questions have copyrights.Beautiful, now do you think you are the only people in the planet wondering that? – slash28cu 4 mins ago

How do we make users understand they are wrong?

Deleting the question might just antagonize them to do it again and/or go on a downvoting rampage, especially since the user sees that they get all their rep back when the question is deleted.

What is the correct way to deal with such a user if it gets to that point?

Comment: How do we deal with a user that doesn't seem to know anything about international copyright law?

Comment: The sarcasm of the comment would indicate that teaching them things shouldn't be a particularly high priority

Comment: Looking at the other content posted by this user, I don't see a pattern of plagiarism, so this might indeed have been an honest mistake. Plagiarism is one of my pet peeves, but I'm willing to give them the benefit of the doubt here. Hopefully, they'll learn from the comments and won't repeat this.

Comment: @BradLarson although most of their questions are posted and within 5 minutes they find the answer themselves. That does not show much research on their part... (of the 4 posted questions by that user)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How do we make users understand they are wrong?

Looking at his comment, there is no point trying to educate the user in this case. It's not a question of knowing the rules, but one of attitude.

Just have the question deleted and be done with it.

If the user goes on a rampage, mod-flag them.

Comment: And eventually, the user will be question-banned.